# How to force cpu full frequency in c#?

Tags: c#, cpu

Im doing benchmarking so i need everything to be full speed. How can I force my cpu to be at full frequency(max turbo frequency) before starting the benchmark?

.net 4.5. My priority is windows. Mono is nice though. My cpu is http://ark.intel.com/products/47925

thanks.

Comment: This can be controlled through Windows' power management UI. Is it really affecting your benchmark so much to be a problem? You should be performing a "warm up" to the benchmark first anyway, to get the code/data hot in cache, which would presumably get your CPU to 100%.

Comment: @corynelson: I wouldn't touch the power settings, if possible. There might be reasons the user has choosen them the way they are. And the application has to work regadless of i.e. the system running on batteries or main power.

Comment: This is not a software problem, it is a plumbing problem.  You'll have to equip your machine with, say, a liquid cpu cooler.  Running benchmarks like this is merely a way to fool yourself, your user is not a plumber either.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry but i don't get what you mean. Why would i have to equip my machine with liquid cooler? Also, the rest of your sentence.

Comment: @CoryNelson Ok. The key word is 'warm up'. Thanks.